# Reading data from URL in Java

Tags: java

I'm getting really confused about this issue and need clarification as soon as anyone can give some.... I apologize for formatting. Right after I try to open the connection, the program seems to simply halt.

```
public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Started to run");

            //The first thing we do is connect with the website and instantiate a Scanner for the data.
            URL address = new URL("http://www.example.com");
            URLConnection connection = address.openConnection();
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("Established connection");

            //We lop off the first 10 blank lines that we'll scan, plus the <body> tag. 
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                scan.nextLine();
            }

            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                synchronized(lock) {//SYNCHRONIZE

                    //First, we check if we've reached the end.
                    String temp = scan.next(); 
                    if (temp.equals("</body>")) {
                        break; //If we have, cease processing.
                    }
                    year = Integer.parseInt(temp); 
                    boyName = scan.next(); boyPrevalence = scan.nextInt(); girlName = scan.next(); 
                    //(Handling the <br> HTML code.)
                    String next = scan.next();
                    next = next.replace("<br>", ""); 
                    girlPrevalence = Integer.parseInt(next);

                    //Now we update our almanac of boys' names for the given year.
                    if(boyNameMap.containsKey(year)) {
                        boyNameMap.get(year).put(boyName, boyPrevalence);
                    } else {
                        Map<String, Integer> tempmap = new HashMap<>();
                        tempmap.put(boyName, boyPrevalence);
                        boyNameMap.put(year, tempmap);
                    }

                    //And now we update our almanac of girls' names.
                    if(girlNameMap.containsKey(year)) {
                        girlNameMap.get(year).put(girlName, girlPrevalence);
                    } else {
                        Map<String, Integer> tempmap = new HashMap<>();
                        tempmap.put(girlName, girlPrevalence);
                        girlNameMap.put(year, tempmap);
                    }

                    System.out.println(year + "; " + boyName + "; " + boyPrevalence + "; "
                            + girlName + "; " + girlPrevalence);

                }//DESYNCHRONIZE
            }
            scan.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }
```

That is, "Established connection" never prints.

Comment: Did you try to debug? If open connection get problem then after a few second try to connection program will throw exception.

Comment: The print statement was me trying to debug, I didn't get any info. The program didn't even make it to the print statement.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Don't understand, what do you mean?

Comment: Do you mean you don't know what a debugger is?

Comment: Well, kind of. I'm using JUnit currently.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144104/discussion-between-chris-and-stephen-c).

Comment: I have tried your code, the problem you present is not happen to me. What is the true url you are using?

Comment: Uh, that could be kind of incriminating. But you say it works for you? Technically I'm not supposed to discuss this; I'm bending the rules because this has me really frustrated.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that your program is unable to contact the webserver for the URL you are really using.  It could be due to incorrect proxy configs, firewalls in various places, and so on.  If you could run your code in a debugger, you would be able to see exactly where it is blocked ... and that would confirm (or not) this explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the code I am trying and the result
[image]

Comment: Well Jesus, that's bizarre. I dunno what my problem is then :/

Comment: Did you try to check if your `run` method is called? If yes let's try shorten your code like mine to test it. Problem still the same then try to restart your IDE...

Comment: My output from elsewhere says that a thread was run, so run() did get called as far as I know.

Comment: Again .... my suggestion to use a debugger!  You need to be sure what is happening here, rather than relying on guesswork / intuition.

Comment: If your `run` method is called then you must see the output: `Started to run` did you see it? Don't guest! Let's try to debug your program

Comment: Yes, even in my original code I saw "started to run". But when I tried your edit, I got that the connection was established

Comment: @StephenC I'm not trying to be difficult but the debugger tutorials I found require main methods, which I haven't written

Comment: Then write the main method for easy to test

Comment: You can run JUnit tests using the debugger without a main method.  Add "junit" to your search terms, or just look in the documentation for Eclipse's JUnit integration.

Comment: Hold on - I wrote a main method which took the scanning part out of the try/catch block, and it worked perfectly. (ie, I just ran it directly without using threads)

Comment: I've been trying to use a thread inner class, which I called MyThread